# Authorisation layer for multi-tenant express applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, architecture, authorization

I've an express API application.

The app's structure is as follows :-

Models :-

- Company.js
- User.js

Controllers :-

- companies.js
- users.js
- authentication.js

Services :-

- passport.js
- authorisation.js

Routers :-

- companies.js
- users.js

My `User` model has a column called `role` which can be either of the following `['superadmin', 'admin', 'user']`.

The model associations are as follows :-

- `Company` has-many `User`
- `User` belongs-to `Company`

The `superadmin` is a role that can make changes across Companies whereas the `admin` and `user` roles are always supposed to be restricted to a Company.

The controllers have basic actions such as `index`, `show`, `create`, `update` and `delete`.

The authorisation middleware ensures that :-

- User with the role of `user` is blocked from accessing the `index`, `create`, `update` and `delete` actions of that controller.
- User with the role of `admin` is blocked from accessing the `index` action of that controller.
- User with the role of `superadmin` is not blocked at all.

The general request flow in my application is such :-

`express router middleware -> passport js authentication -> path specific router -> user role authorisation -> controller action -> response to the user`

Due to this approach, I currently have to check for the User `role` within the controller whether the User is an `admin` or a `superadmin` within my `index`, `create`, `update`, `delete` actions. I don't like the approach because I feel that controller should be lean and only have Model manipulation logic, not conditional logic to handle multiple cases.

To solve this, I thought of separating the `superadmin` role accessible functionality into an entirely separate controller and group the admin and user role accessible functionality into another controller.

Is this the way I should proceed or are there other ways to design authorisation for multi-tenant applications in express?

Thanks for reading, please advise.

Comment: Try https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles  just add the connect-roles middileware after passport middleware, like this: app.use(authentication);app.use(connectRoles.middleware());